# Creating multiple views from Entityform Submissions

Tags: views, entities

I would like to create multiple views containing filtered/ordered results from submissions made into forms created using EntityForm.

In the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1806662) and in question on DA([The Entityform module allows me to create forms that any user can submit and the forms fields are available for me to use in views, similar to how a content type would work.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46387/getting-a-fields-value-from-an-entity) it seems this is possible but I cannot figure out how.

Fields created and submitted in the forms are not listed under "add field" in views, nor in "add relationship".

So the question is:

How is it possible to fully interrogate Entityform submitted data using views?

**THE SOLUTION:**
As per Wolverine's answer it is very simple to do, displayed in the picture:

[image: views-entityform]

No idea how I missed it before!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be available, create a view of `Entityform Submission` and add the filter `Entityform Type`, if you want. Add the fields that you want to display, make sure you have selected `Show : Fields` under **Format** section.

By default entity form module creates two views, Entityforms & Entityform Type List, you can edit the `Entityforms` view instead creating a new view, if you want.

Comment: Thanks Wolverine, you are 100% correct. Thank you for phrasing it in the way you did, I had been trying to do it for a whole day, not sure how I missed that option. I will add a walk-through @ https://www.drupal.org/node/2296851 anyway as I have not seen one anywhere.